# How do I have anonymous notifications (phone, text, ...) on Android 4.3 like 4.1?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.3-jelly-bean

So back in what I believe was Android 4.1, I had to swipe my lock screen to unlock my phone. Before swiping, it gives me the option of swiping into my missed calls, my text messages, and my applications. It did not show who I missed a call from, nor did it show the contents of my text message.

Now it shows both. How can I stop my phone from displaying private messages and communication?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer to my question, so I won't mark it as accepted just yet.

If you go to Messages / Menu button / Settings / Notification settings there should be a setting called "Preview message". Uncheck this and text messages will not show up in your lock screen.

I have not figured out how to do this for calls though.